# Text and buttons are extending outside parent container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some text and buttons within a chat_bubble parent div. If there's too much text, or if the screen is too small, the text and buttons extend outside the parent container.

I need btn-grid to have a fixed height of 20% of question-container, and for question-text to fill the remaining space. What do I need to do?

Here is a codepen:

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/JjWVbKJ

Here is my CSS:

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Benne', serif;
    font-size: 10vh;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.25;
}

:root {
    --hue-neutral: 200;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.btn-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    gap: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    height: 20%;
}

.btn {
    background-color: purple;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 5vh;
}

.btn:hover {
    border-color: black;
}

.start-btn, .next-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.controls {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

#main {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#chat_bubble    {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    background: ghostwhite !important;
    float: left;
}

#character_image  {
    max-height: 30vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    background: #ffffff;
    float: right;
    overflow: visible;
}

#question-text {
    object-fit: cover;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the question container with text and buttons to be scrollable if there is many lines of question text before the buttons?

Comment: Nope, I need the font-size to be responsive to fit regardless of how much text there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the `#question` text to be responsive and fit to its parent container regardless of the amount of question text. You can achieve "responsive text" aka [fluid typography](https://css-tricks.com/simplified-fluid-typography/) with the help of [`clamp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()) which essentially "clamps" a value between a lower and upper bound. It has good support or you could go with a [relative length unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#lengths) like `vw` and introduce breakpoints to resize the font at smaller screens if you don't want to use `clamp()`.

Now `.btn-grid` occupies a fixed 20% height inside the `#question-container` and question text fills the remaining space in the parent container. Regardless how much text there is, the `#question-container` will grow in height and the font-size will increase/decrease as the viewport is varied in a responsive manner.

```js
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn')
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container')
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
const answerButtonsElement = document.getElementById('answer-buttons')
const emailContainerElement = document.getElementById('email-container')
const submitEmailButton = document.getElementById('submit-email-btn')
const email = document.getElementById('email')
const chartContainer = document.getElementById('chart')

startButton.classList.add('hide')
emailContainerElement.classList.add('hide')
questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide')

questionElement.innerText = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'

const button_no = document.createElement('button')
button_no.innerText = 'No'
button_no.classList.add('btn')
answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button_no)
const button_yes = document.createElement('button')
button_yes.innerText = 'No'
button_yes.classList.add('btn')
answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button_yes)
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Benne', serif;
    font-size: 10vh;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 1.25;
}

:root {
    --hue-neutral: 200;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
}

#question {
    font-size: 16px; /* fallback */
    font-size: clamp(1em, 5vw, 10vh);
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.btn-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    gap: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    height: 20%;
}

.btn {
    background-color: purple;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 5vh;
}

.btn:hover {
    border-color: black;
}

.start-btn, .next-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.controls {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

#main {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#chat_bubble    {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    background: ghostwhite !important;
    float: left;
}

#character_image  {
    max-height: 30vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    background: #ffffff;
    float: right;
    overflow: visible;
}

#question-text {
    height:50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test title</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Benne&family=Fjalla+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="chat_bubble" class="container">
        <div id="email-container" class="hide">
            <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
            <button id="submit-email-btn" class="btn">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div id="question-container" class="hide">
            <div id="question" class="question-text">Question</div>
            <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="chart" class="hide"></div>
        <div class="controls">
            <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="character_image">
        <img src="http://media.pixcove.com/C/0/9/Stick-Figure-Figure-Stick-Free-Vector-Graphics-Fre-0800.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>

</div>


<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script defer src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```